# Xorg separate X screens with internal and external graphics card

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, xorg, integrated-graphics

I have a motherboard (Asus P8Z77-V) that has an internal graphics card (Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor video card) and external pcie nVidia GT610.

Is it possible to have one separate xscreen running on the internal card and another one on the external card? Or is only the Xinerama possible with current hw-configuration?